# Is ADSB required in Class C airspace when the tower is closed?

Tags: faa-regulations, ads-b, far-91, class-c-airspace

Many Class C airspaces do not have a full-time tower and the airspace reverts to Class E or G when the tower is closed. The wording in CFR Part 91 § 91.225 doesn’t specifically say whether ADSB is required when the tower is closed and I can’t find any guidance from the FAA or AOPA on the matter.

> (d)…no person may operate an aircraft in the following airspace unless
> the aircraft has equipment installed that meets the requirements in
> paragraph (b) of this section:
>
> (1) Class B and Class C airspace areas
>
> …
>
> (3) Above the ceiling and
> within the lateral boundaries of a Class B or Class C airspace area
> designated for an airport upward to 10,000 feet MSL;

Comment: As when the tower is closed the airspace is E/G, then your question boils down to "is ADSB required in class E/G". Right? See [also](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/aircraft-and-ownership/ads-b/where-is-ads-b-out-required).

Comment: @mins Not exactly. The question boils down to whether the reversion to Class G or E also changes the requirement for ADSB or whether the Class C as depicted on the chart is in effect no matter what the status of the tower.

Comment: @JScarry: RE "whether the Class C as depicted on the chart": the chart like the chart supplement also notes what happens, e.g. [Mobile Class C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjehR.png) from the [sectional](https://skyvector.com/?ll=28.500594211751487,-91.37516738879252&chart=34&zoom=5). If you've meant something else, then it might be worth adding to the question body.

Comment: Are there any Class B or Class C airspaces that would be excluded by the phrase *designated for an airport*?  Why did they stick that in there?  Another ASE question in the making--

Comment: @quietflyer According to https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO_Order_7400.11F_508.pdf there are no Class C currently that do not have an airport. I suppose it’s possible that when military facilities are shut down the Class C airspace could remain without a tower for a while.

Answer (score 6):

If an airspace is only class C when the tower is in operation, then it is no longer class C airspace when the tower is closed.   In that case, the rules applicable to the class E or G airspace apply rather than class C, because the airspace is not class C at that time.

Comment: I would concur. The tower being open or closed has no bearing on the ADS-B requirement, **except** insofar as it affects what class of airspace is in effect.